# Joomla ACL custom actions

Tags: joomla2.5

I'm creating a custom (1.6) component wherein users can book a camp site.  Users will be required to log in if they want to use funds/credits that they already have stored.  Only certain groups can use these funds/credits.

I have created an access.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<access component="com_propbooker">
  <section name="booking">
    <action name="booking.create" title="Book Site" description="Allows users of this group to book sites." />
  </section>
</access>
```

and my config.xml file:

```
<config>
  <fieldset name="API Configuration" label="API Configuration">
    <field name="google_api_key" label="Google API Key" type="text" size="50" default="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset name="Booking Permissions" label="Booking Permissions" description="Set Groups that can book sites">
    <field name="booking_permission" label="Booking Permission" type="rules" class="inputbox" validate="rules" filter="rules" component="com_propbooker" section="booking" />
  </fieldset>
</config>
```

It all shows up fine when I click the options button, but no changes are ever saved.  It always flips back to "Inherited" when i click the "Save" button.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `permissions` as the fieldset name and `rules` as the fieldname in your config.xml.
Like this:

```
<fieldset name="permissions"
    label="JCONFIG_PERMISSIONS_LABEL"
    description="JCONFIG_PERMISSIONS_DESC" >
    <field name="rules"
        type="rules"
        label="JCONFIG_PERMISSIONS_LABEL"
        class="inputbox"
        validate="rules"
        filter="rules"
        component="com_propbooker"
        section="booking"
    />
</fieldset>
```

I would also consider using the section name `component` as it is the default naming. But your needs may be different.

Comment: TYVM, the devil is always in the details.